# Prolog unification process (concat)

Tags: prolog, concatenation

The following code works, but I have certain doubts as to how it does things under the hood. For example, on the first call to Exit(9) I don't understand how c is moved to the variable O. Is this part of the unification process or something else entirely? Care anyone to explain?

```
concat([], List, List).
concat([Head|[]], List, [Head|List]).
concat([Head|Tail], List, Concat) :- concat(Tail, List, C), concat([Head], C, Concat).
```

[image: trace]

Answer (score 1):

You can do 'by hand' the unification process, to verify that the trace line labelled Exit:(9) actually 'cons-ed'  [c] to [x,y,z]:

```
?- [Head|[]]=[c],List=[x,y,z],[Head|List]=O.
Head = c,
List = [x, y, z],
O = [c, x, y, z].
```

but, you cannot claim it works:

```
?- concat([a,b,c],[x,y,z],L).
L = [a, b, c, x, y, z] ;
L = [a, b, c, x, y, z] ;
...
```

it doesn't *terminate*, and this clearly indicate some problem. The second clause is redundant - both in behaviour and syntax. It would be usually written like

```
concat([Head], List, [Head|List]).
```

since the empty tail list it's *implicitly* present in every list - except where a tail is explicitly indicated:

```
?- [Head|[]]=[X].
Head = X.
```

About the behaviour, you can see from your trace that it's the *first* clause that is never used. So, you can think it's the first that is redundant - maybe you added the second because of the last call of the third clause, where a 'singleton' list is required (I mean `...,concat([Head], C, Concat).`). But such call it's causing the non termination issue. Better to simplify the whole program, removing the second clause and simplifying the third....